# Adding dataTable into dataset is allways empty althout DataTable has rows

Tags: datatable, dataset

I have a Dataset with results I get from the DB, I keep that as a base dataset and would like any filtering will be done on the second Dataset.

I ensure I have the filtered data on datatable but when I use dataset.table.add

the dataset is always empty

code below

```
 protected void showMembers(Boolean filtered=false)
        {
            using (var cn = GetConnection())
            {
                cn.Open();
                string cmsGetProfiles = "SELECT * FROM [Vm_siteMembers] order by [Last Login Time] desc ";
                                
                SqlDataAdapter EventsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmsGetProfiles, cn);
                BaseMembersListDS.Clear();// this DataSet defined as public static

                EventsAdapter.Fill(BaseMembersListDS);

                using (DataSet filteredMemberListDS = new DataSet())
                {
                    filteredMemberListDS.Merge(BaseMembersListDS.Tables[0]);
                    if (filtered)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.TableName = "filtered";
                                                                       
                        filteredMemberListDS.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in BaseMembersListDS.Tables[0].Columns)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
                        }
                        foreach (DataRow dr in BaseMembersListDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(5))
                            dt.ImportRow(dr);
                            
                        filteredMemberListDS.Tables.Add(dt);
                    }
                    MembersdataBind(filteredMemberListDS);//why filteredMemberListDS is empty
                }
            }
        }

        protected void MembersdataBind(DataSet filteredMemberList)
        {

            MemebersDdl.DataSource = filteredMemberList;
            MemebersDdl.DataBind();
        }
```

Columns headers on datatable match by doing this

```
foreach (var item in BaseMembersListDS.Tables[0].Columns)
                            dt.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
```